# Vertically spacing TextViews in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout and I want to add 3 TextViews vertically. That I can do.

My question is: how do get the TextViews to evenly space themselves out vertically within my LinearLayout which happens to be 800x600 pixels.

Given that the LinearLayout is 600 pixels high, that would mean positioning the 3 lines of text on lines y=150, y=300, y=450 (approximately).

How would I create an XML file to do that even vertical spacing?

Note: I don't want to use absolute coordinates.

Comment: you need to use gravity and weight for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is the code to evenly manage your text view just copy paste it

when you use weight and gravity in your xml code for designing it will automatically adjust on all screen

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the weight attribute to make the TextView's scale to the size of the window. Furthermore you can specify the gravity attribute to make the text inside of the `TextView`'s be centered.

In this code, the `TextView`'s each take up 1/3 of the screen:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="tv1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="tv1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="tv1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where's `android:weightSum=3` on the root LinearLayout?

Comment: @Losin'Me the weightSum is not necessary here as it is calculated implicitly and set to 3.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I will give those a try later!

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the help of `layout_weight`

---

***Sample***

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="text2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="text3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```